# Shopify custom payment method API

Tags: shopify

Researched the Shopify API references but cannot find the answer. Is there a way to use Custom payment method in Shopify? I want to use a custom developed payment method that is not in the supported Third Party Payment method list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just make your own payment methods. If you made one that you want to use with Shopify, you have to conform to Shopify standards for the development (activemerchant) and then submit your payment method to them for review. If they find your custom payment gateway would serve the better larger Shopify merchant base, they can turn your custom payment gateway into one used with Shopify.

Otherwise, you would be better off transacting with your custom gateway using your own custom shop, running Spree for example.

Comment: I want to make my payment method (coin method) would you please train me how is this possible.

Comment: It is not possible with Shopify. You can use your own code for your own commerce system that way. Try using Spree for example. With that you can make your own payments system!

Comment: But I show(find)the way shopify provide https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/payment-gateway

Comment: So ask for their approval. If you get it, you can get started.